# cpp static object instantiation

Tags: c++, oop, static

I am newbie to CPP.
I need to add static member that can be called from a static method.
So in the .h i declare it:

```
static uint32_t s_MyStaticMember;
```

Above my constructor (in the "namespace") I initialize it:

```
uint32_t MyClassName::s_MyStaticMember;
```

Now I can use this static member from my static method.
The question is, if I initialize the member with =0;

```
uint32_t MyClassName::s_MyStaticMember=0;"
```

What will happen on the next instantiation of the class ?
I assume it will not reset the static member to 0 because this is the reason the initialize is out of the class, the =0 will happen **only once**.

Is my assumption correct ?

Comment: You can only ever instantiate something once.  Trying to do so again is an error.

Comment: @NathanOliver The question is if by defining in the global with =0; wont set the value of the existing instance to 0 each time the object is created. It does not make sense, i just want to validate this

Comment: I'm saying you can't do `uint32_t MyClassName::s_MyStaticMember;` followed by `uint32_t MyClassName::s_MyStaticMember = 0;`.  That is a redefinition and not allowed.  If that's not what you are asking then having a [mre] would be helpful.

Comment: @NathanOliver I dont mean to redefine it, i meant, modify the line in code and recompile, instead of member; to do member=1. The below answer is the correct, my assumption was true, thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static variables are only initialized once, in the static initialization phase of program startup (reference: [[basic.start.static]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.start.static)). The compiler is responsible for making sure there's only one instance of `Counted::count`, and that it gets initialized exactly once, before any of your other code runs.

Note that if you don't explicitly initialize a static (so you just define it without the `= 0`), it is anyway zero-initialized by default.

Constucting instances of your class has no effect on non-instance (ie, static) members at all, *unless* your constructor explicitly writes to them, eg.

```
struct Counted {
  static unsigned count;
  Counted() { ++count; }
  ~Counted() { --count; }
};

unsigned Counted::count;
```

the constructor *does* alter the static, but it *doesn't* re-initialize it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Static member variables are akin to global variables in a namespace. They only have one instance. Their initialization will happen only once before the execution even enters your main().